# Not able to delete certain materials from blendfile

Tags: materials, linked-data, data-blocks

I'm having trouble deleting certain materials from my blendfile.

In the example below you can see that the material appears to have multiple users while in fact there are no other objects in the scene that have this material assigned.

[image]

In the material browser the material shows as follow:
*(however it should be called ''0 old Red Leather'' if no other users have this material assigned if I'm correct)*

[image]

I've tried unhiding all objects, selecting linked materials by pressing SHIFT+L, saving and reopening the blendfile  but none of these methods seem to work.

What else could I do to delete these materials from the blendfile?

Comment: could you share the file through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can check it?

Comment: @m.ardito I can't share the blendfile as it is subject to a NDA.

Comment: can you try duplicating the file, then on the copy delete all objects, then examine the material: it should become orphan, imho.

Comment: You should be able to press X button to the right of the materials dropdown while holding Shift key. It will remove any users of that datablock from the file and the 0 number will appear next to the material name.